# Images and videos are not showing on netlify

Tags: javascript, html, css, netlify

I made a website on VS code.Images and videos are showing in my laptop chrome browser after opening html file but when I deploy it manually on netlify hosting website.My website is hosting but images and videos are not showing.plz tell me solution of my problem

I tried to deploy my website.I expected images and videos will show after deploying it on netlify hosting site but images and videos are not showing

Comment: have you uploaded images and videos on netlify ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.